# Select2 Initialize select after appending data to existing select

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

In my select2 select, i need to append li after document is ready, and after appending, how can i reinitialize select2. If I once close and again open the select, the appended data are selectable but not as soon as i append.
How can i reinitialize it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have to destroy the select2 on these elements and then reinitialize it.

```
$("select").select2("destroy").select2();
```

Comment: thanks, it did the magic and i added $("select").select2("open"); to reopen it.

Comment: I'm getting an error: The select2('destroy') method was called on an element that is not using Select2.

Comment: @Jonathan that means the elements you select haven't been initialized by select2 using `.select2()`.

Comment: I have like 5 dropdowns well initialized! even tried to target 1 , but still getting the same error

Comment: Then its hard to see the cause of this without code. Best will be to create a new question for this with code samples so we can see it.

Comment: Very useful when using a select2 in a modal

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Mivaweb for answer above ^

So if I use:

```
$("select").select2("destroy").select2();
```

then I'm getting following issue as some guys in comments on answer above:

```
The select2('destroy') method was called on an element that is not using Select2
```

But it does not mean that it is not working, it works, but need to update approach a bit.

**Working solution for me:**

STEP1: destroy existing select2 instances

STEP2: update options or select

STEP3: and now init new select2 instances

**For example:**

```
$(".select2me-filter").select2("destroy");

... Here do option updates you need

$(".select2me-filter").select2();
```

Answer (score 0):

A little addition to [@Mivaweb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27561619/8369356)'s answer. If you get the error message "The select2('destroy') method was called on an element that is not using Select2", then you can do the following:

```
if ($("select").hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
    // Select2 has been initialized
    $("select").select2("destroy");
}
```

And then you can reinitialize: `$("select").select2();`